# List a class's generic superclasses?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, reflection

I have an inheritance hierarchy:

```
public interface IValidator<TItem>

public abstract class Validator<TItem, TId> : IValidator<IItem>

public class MyValidator : Validator<MyItem, int>
```

I want to find every interface and superclass of `MyValidator`.  I can do the interfaces easily with

```
return validator.GetType().GetInterfaces();
```

But when I try the same for superclasses, all I get back is `System.Object`, not `Validator<MyItem, int>`.

```
var type = validator.GetType();
return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(supertype => type.IsSubclassOf(supertype));
```

How can I get the full inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: `a.GetTypes()` does not get constructed types. But why are you not using `typeof(MyValidator).BaseType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over each and every type in your assembly you can check base types. Also, you don't need an instance of `MyValidator` to get `MyValidator` type. Check this code:

```
var baseType = typeof(MyValidator).BaseType;
var baseTypes = new List<Type> { baseType };

while(baseType != typeof(object))
    baseTypes.Add(baseType = baseType.BaseType);
```

Now `baseTypes` list contains `Validator<MyItem, int>` and `object` types.

Comment: what for while loop ? `MyValidator` can have only one base class

Comment: @Z.R.T. sure, but base class of `MyValidator` may have base class too

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be that easy and I somehow missed that one every time.